# Grouping and aggregating over columns duplicates columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am joining two tables `left_table` and `right_table` on non-unique keys that results in row explosion. I then want to aggregate rows to match the number of rows in `left_table`. To do this I aggregate over left_table columns.
Weirdly, when I save the table the columns in `left_table` double. It seems like columns of `left_table` become an index for resulting dataframe...

Left table

```
    k1  k2   s   v  c  target
0   1   3  20  40  2       2
1   1   2  10  20  1       1
2   1   2  10  80  2       1
```

Right table

```
    k11  k22  s2   v2
0    1    2   0  100
1    2    3  30  200
2    1    2  10  300
```

Left join

```
    k1  k2   s   v  c  target    s2     v2
0   1   3  20  40  2       2   NaN    NaN
1   1   2  10  20  1       1   0.0  100.0
2   1   2  10  20  1       1  10.0  300.0
3   1   2  10  80  2       1   0.0  100.0
4   1   2  10  80  2       1  10.0  300.0
```

Aggregation code

```
dic = {}
keys_to_agg_over = left_table_col_names

for col in numeric_cols:
    if col in all_cols:
           dic[col] = 'median'

left_join = left_join.groupby(keys_to_agg_over).aggregate(dic)
```

After aggregation (doubled number of left table cols)

```
                       k1  k2   s   v  c  target   s2     v2
k1 k2 s  v  c target                                       
1  2  10 20 1 1        1   2  10  20  1       1  5.0  200.0
         80 2 1        1   2  10  80  2       1  5.0  200.0
   3  20 40 2 2        1   3  20  40  2       2  NaN    NaN
```

Saved to csv file

```
k1,k2,s,v,c,target,k1,k2,s,v,c,target,s2,v2
1,2,10,20,1,1,1,2,10,20,1,1,5.0,200.0
1,2,10,80,2,1,1,2,10,80,2,1,5.0,200.0
1,3,20,40,2,2,1,3,20,40,2,2,,
```

I tried resetting index, as `left_join.reset_index()` but I get

```
ValueError: cannot insert target, already exists
```

How to fix the issue of column-doubling?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Store csv not including the index: I guess you are using the `to_csv` method to store the result in a csv. By default it includes you index columns in the generated csv. you can do `to_csv(index=False)` to avoid storing them.
2. reset_index dropping it: you can use `left_join.reset_index(drop=True)` in order to discard the index columns and not add them in the dataframe. By default reset_index adds the current index columns to the dataframe, generating the `ValueError` you obtain.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using:

```
left_join = left_table.merge(right_table, left_on = ["k1", "k2"], "right_on" = ["k11", "k22"] , how = "left")
```

This will result in a dataframe with repeated rows since indexes 1 and 2 from the left table both can be joined to indexes 0 and 2 of the right table. If that is the behavior you expected, and just want to get rid of duplicated rows you can try using:

```
left_join = left_join.drop_duplicates()
```

Before aggregating. This solution won't stop duplicating rows, it will rather eliminate them to not cause any trouble.

You can also pass the parameter as_index = False in the groupby function like this:

```
left_join = left_join.groupby(keys_to_agg_over, as_index = False).aggregate(dic)
```

To stop geting the "grouping columns" as indexes.